# Cron emails output even when redirecting to /dev/null 2>&1

Tags: cron

The code below should redirect all output to /dev/null however root still receives an email with output from the first command (/usr/bin/svnadmin). Why?

```
#!/bin/sh
# Dump repo and upload via tarsnap

/usr/bin/svnadmin dump /srv/repos/www | gzip > /srv/repos/backup/www-repo-`date --iso-8601`.gz > /dev/null 2>&1
/usr/local/bin/tarsnap -c -f www-repo-`date --iso-8601` /srv/repos/backup/www-repo-`date --iso-8601`.gz > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have piped the second commands STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null, and only piped the first command's STDOUT to the second command. So the first command's STDERR is e-mail-ed to you.

You should write

```
( /usr/bin/svnadmin dump /srv/repos/www | gzip > /srv/repos/backup/www-repo-`date --iso-8601`.gz ) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

With my reputation I can't add comments, so I'll have to submit an answer allthough I'm not sure this is the case.

**What does your crontab look like?** I don't think it's your script that sends the e-mail, cron/crontab is doing that. So please show us contents of your crontab (crontab -e).

I might be wrong (I actually used cron myself for the first time just yesterday), but I think you should have the `> /dev/null 2>&1` part in your crontab rather than in your script file. So your crontab could look something like this:

```
@hourly /your/script/location > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Hope this helps.